# Certificate disappearing from Trusted Root Certification store

Tags: ssl, certificate, trusted-root-certificates

I am using a self-signed certificate for testing SSL locally on my development environment - I insert the certificate into my trusted certification store and everything is fine, but a few hours later it has disappeared!

Does anybody know why a certificate would constantly disappear from the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, to stop this happening, I had to add the certificate to both the Registry & Local stores under Trusted Root Certification storage.

Odd, but it works.